# Can my Spotify app require the user to enter a license code to unlock it?

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

I am looking to monetize a Spotify app.

Since Spotify doesn't presently have a way for apps to be sold, I wonder if I can have the user purchase a license on my website, which they would then enter into the app to start using it. The flow would be as follows:

- user learns about the app, visits my website and purchases a license
- user finds the app on Spotify and adds it
- user enter license code into the app to unlock it

I couldn't find any mention to payments on Spotify's terms of service.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer: I am a Spotify employee, but I haven't worked on this feature personally.**

Every Spotify app must pass the [approval process](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/process/) before it is published and distributed. The experience you've proposed will almost certainly fail this item from the [app design guidelines](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/design/):

> **Be here now.** Don’t add features that force users to go out to your
>   website. Users don’t like disjointed experiences so make all
>   functionality work within Spotify.

Additionally, the [terms of use](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/terms-of-use/) specify that you must agree to a standard distribution agreement. While that agreement isn't publicly available, having an app that requires going out to your website to purchase a license is probably not going to fly.

Comment: Without knowing your idea, perhaps a freemium model would work.  Basic functionality for free, pay for extra functionality.  I think submitting your idea for approval is the only way you'll really be able to answer this question.